# Copy and save worksheet as new spreadsheet with given name in current folder

Tags: excel, vba

Wrote code to save files. The below is the shorter version which only saves one worksheet.

Sometimes it works, but most of the time it silently crashes Excel with no error warning.

Nothing wrong while debugging. Not sure if `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` might be causing the issue.

```vb
Sub Save_CPC()

'Define the sheets to copy
Dim sheetsToCopy As Variant
sheetsToCopy = Array("RWF CPC")

'Create a new workbook
Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

'Loop through the sheets to copy
For i = 0 To UBound(sheetsToCopy)
    'Copy the sheet to the new workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsToCopy(i)).Copy Before:=newWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next i

'Break links in the new workbook
newWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.Name, Type:=xlExcelLinks

'Hide the sheet Sheet1 in new workbook
newWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = False

'Save the new workbook in the original folder
Dim saveName As String
saveName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macros").Range("B13").Value
newWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & saveName & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Should copy and save worksheet as new spreadsheet with given name in current folder.

Comment: Side note, but if you `.Copy` a worksheet with no destination, it'll create a new workbook, so there's no need for `newWorkbook` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Worksheets To a New Workbook

**In One Go**

- Note that you can copy all the worksheets in one go as suggested by BigBen in the comments:

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsToCopy).Copy
  Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook: Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
  ```
- The major drawback is that the worksheets in the new workbook will appear in the order they are appearing in the old workbook which may not necessarily be the order they are appearing in the array.
- Additionally, at least one of the worksheets needs to be visible, and **very hidden** worksheets will not be copied.

**Loop**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveCPC()

    ' Start error-handling routine.
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    ' Populate an array with the names of the worksheets to copy.
    Dim sheetsToCopy() As Variant: sheetsToCopy = VBA.Array("RWF CPC")
    ' 'VBA.' ensures a zero-based array no matter what ('Option Base'-related).
    ' If you don't do this, instead of both occurrences of '0',
    ' use the recommended (more accurate) 'LBound(sheetsToCopy)'.
    
    ' Declare new variables to be used in the loop.
    Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook, OldWorksheet As Worksheet, i As Long
    
    ' Loop through the worksheet names in the array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(sheetsToCopy)
        ' Reference the worksheet to be copied.
        Set OldWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetsToCopy(i))
        If i = 0 Then ' on the first iteration...
            ' Add a new workbook containing only the first copied worksheet.
            OldWorksheet.Copy
            ' Reference this new workbook.
            Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Else ' on any but the first iteration
            ' Copy the worksheet as the last sheet in the new workbook.
            OldWorksheet.Copy After:=NewWorkbook.Sheets(NewWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Break links in the new workbook.
    NewWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.Name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
    
    ' Retrieve the base name of the new workbook.
    Dim saveName As String
    saveName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macros").Range("B13").Value
    
    ' Save the new workbook in the original folder.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation.
        NewWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & saveName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "CPC saved.", vbInformation

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    ' Continue error-handling routine.
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```